# Powershell try catch doesn't catch the errors

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to get some processes and if there aren't any, i want to catch it with the error message "Es ist ein Problem aufgetreten". I tried the following, but catching did not work.
Any idea, why ?

```
function stop-FileHandle ([string[]]$Processes) {
        $Error.Clear()
        try {
            foreach ($Process in $Processes) {
                #Stop-Process -Id ($Process -split(":") | Select-Object -Last 1)
                #"foreach schleife: " + $ProcessID
                #"get-process command: "
                Get-Process -Id ($Process -split(":") | Select-Object -Last 1) | Write-Output $_ 
            }
        }
        catch {
            "Es ist ein Problem aufgetreten" +$Error
        }
        if (!$Error) {
            Write-Host "Die folgenden Prozesse mit den folgenden ProcessIDs wurden beendet:"
            $Processes
        }    
        #$Processes
    
    }
```

Event though error occurs, the catch section doesn't run. But the error is shown on the console:

```
Get-Process : Es kann kein Prozess mit der Prozess-ID 6216 gefunden werden. In Zeile:9 Zeichen:13
+             Get-Process -Id ($Process -split(":") | Select-Object -La ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (6216:Int32) [Get-Process], ProcessCommandException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoProcessFoundForGivenId,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand
```

Comment: I would suggest looking up the difference between terminating and non-terminating errors in PowerShell. (Short answer workaround is to use `-ErrorAction Stop` if you want the `catch` block to catch these.)

Comment: In addition to Bill's comment, another option is to set the variable to `Stop`: `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` (this could be done on the `begin {...}` block of your function or at the top of your script, outside the function's scope).

Comment: that captures only one error message. the variable processes has more processids. because -erroraction stop will occur direct after the first looping, only the first line of the variable will be checked and then the looping will be stoped. How can i loop through all lines in this variable and at  the end go to catch  ?

Comment: @keeran put the `try { } catch { }` inside the loop instead of outside.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how you want to feed the processes this might work:

```
function stop-FileHandle ([string[]]$Processes) {
$Error.Clear()
foreach ($Process in $Processes) {
    try {            
        #Stop-Process -Id ($Process -split(":") | Select-Object -Last 1)
        #"foreach schleife: " + $ProcessID
        #"get-process command: "
        Get-Process -erroraction stop -Id ($Process -split(":") | Select-Object -Last 1) | Write-Output $_ 
    }
    catch {
        "Es ist ein Problem aufgetreten" +$Error
    }
    if (!$Error) {
        Write-Host "Die folgenden Prozesse mit den folgenden ProcessIDs wurden beendet:"
        $Processes
    }    
    #$Processes
}
```

}

If you have an error that you can read you can be more specific by extracting the exception like:

```
$Error[0].exception.getType().Fullname
```

Put the result between square brackets like so:

```
Catch [System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException]{...}
```

This will catch this specific error. You can add another specific catch or a generic one like you already did.
Furthermore you don't need the if statement as, when all goes well, this can be processes in the try.